# What does "tiles" usually mean in a GIS context?

Tags: tiles, rendering, optimization

I've seen the word thrown around a lot and from the way I've heard it used, there is an approach to dividing the world up into squares with various zoom levels as an effort to speed up web rendering. So that rather than downloading one large file, we clip the large file up into the squares and only have to download the square we're looking at. Used in context of both raster and vector.

Is this what tiles means in GIS with the correlation that we're talking about optimizing web rendering?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question is quite generic, and is probably answered by some research on the web. In short, your own answer to your question is valid. Think of having to download a huge tile with a meter resolution for the whole world. Some examples [here](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/#1/0.51/19.96)

Comment: Sorry for the poor description. I've heard it used as a "tile map server", "gdal2tiles", "generating dynamic tiles", "requesting tiles", "XYZ tiles" for example. I think I can see the thread where they all connect but just wanted to make sure I wasn't completely off base. So tilemapserver is serving the cut up squares of data on the web, gdal2tiles is cutting your data into the squares so you have it prepared, in contrast generating dynamic tiles is clipping your data up on the fly on request, requesting tiles is asking for specific squares, XYZ tiles is the layout of the squares. Accurate?

Comment: Not that your description is poor, it is well described. It is just a bit broad with regards to the [GIS SE scope](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Questions should be about an "actual problem". Your question might get closed for that.  To your point: I am not an expert in that matter, but the way you describe is sounds totally correct

Comment: Sometimes "tiles" can also refer to source data. See https://mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html.

Answer (score 0):

A "tile" in a GIS context is data concerning a 2-dimensional area. There are "raster tiles" and "vector tiles".

### Raster tiles

Raster tiles are [raster images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) and are commonly 256x256 pixels.
Raster tiles can be created using raster and/or vector data. An examples of rasterized data is satellite imagery. An example of vector data is the vector-based shape of a building (seen from the top).

Here are a few examples:

[image: a vector tile for part of the Netherlands]
[image: a raster tile for part of Germany]
[image: a vector tile for part of Germany]

### Vector tiles

A vector tile is not a file but a bit of data. This could be the contents of a JSON file for instance.

There are different specifications for vector tiles, but [here's the one](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1) Mapbox uses.

Sources:

- https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/706
- https://support.esri.com/en-us/gis-dictionary/tiling
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_tiles
- https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-introduction/

Lastly: I think definitional questions are valid for GIS SE. And I'm not a GIS expert so I hope [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) works.